# OAUTH installation on ubuntu server. Not getting reflecting

Tags: php, ubuntu, oauth

After reading from web and forum done successfull installation of OAuth (pecl package)

Doing pecl list - 
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:

Package Version State

oauth   1.0.0   stable

Also updated the php.ini file at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

with extension=oauth.so

But nothing shown at Phpinfo and also getting error
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's mod_php, you need to restart the Apache server so it picks it up.

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Otherwise try loading the module manually with `dl()` first, to see if it works at all.

Comment: it was not getting loaded. Some error to do with php 5.2 and 5.3. Given extension directory separately and worked. Thanks...